# Quickblox changing the opponent in 1 to 1 chat

Tags: php, api, quickblox

I am using the the latest version of quick blox from

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Here i am using the demo 1-1 chat and i have changed it to the user of the app that i have created

[image]

It is working good, and i can able to login

But after the login i can see only the opponent as Quick always like the below screen

[image]

**How can i add another user of my application as opponent ?**

I can find that the opponent was declared here

```
var opponent = chooseOpponent(chatUser.login);
```

But where does the `chatUser.login` comes from.

**So, I don't know how to have the opponent as the some user ? How can i have it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use latest Chat updates here

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Demo - http://quickblox.github.io/quickblox-javascript-sdk/samples/chat

The sample you use is from deprecated js sdk